# IBAction in UIView - Compatible with MVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, ibaction

I'm trying to understand the implementation of the MVC-Pattern in iOS Apps with Objective-C.

Right now I have a DataProvider object which holds and provides my data to other objects in my application (Model).

Furthermore I have a View (.xib) with an additional class (`UIView`; lets call it "ViewClass"). I told my view to be a subclass of my ViewClass so that I'm able to create `IBOutlet`s to my subviews like labels and `IBAction`s to my buttons. So this is obviously my View in the MVC-Pattern.

Last but not least, I have a `ViewController` object which has a reference to my DataProvider and which holds an object of my View. When the `ViewController` is loaded into memory, it instances the View in `viewDidLoad` and adds it to its own view by calling `addSubview:(UIView *)view`. This is my Controller in the MVC-Pattern.

So far so good, but what I do not understand is the following. According to the MCV-Pattern, the View should only display data provided by the `ViewController` which gets the data from the Model. Any logical operation should only happen in the `ViewController` as it is responsible for this kind of tasks.
But if I create an `IBAction` in my "`ViewClass`", I'm forced to have some kind of programming logic in my View.

Lets say I would like to submit a form with data the user entered in some textfield by clicking a button. In my `ViewClass` I have an `IBOutlet` to the textfield to be able to reference it later and read the data the user entered. And I have an `IBAction` to the button to be able to catch the click event. The code to send the data is now written in the `IBAction` Method in my View so I have program logic in my View.

To my question: Isn't this a breach against the MVC-Pattern?

I could possibly pass a reference of my `ViewController` to my View while I create an instance of the View and then call a method of my `ViewController` in the `IBAction` which then gets and sends the data.
But I can't really imagine that this is the right approach. Or do I understand something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might have not understood your example, but why don't you put the IBAction into the View Controller? The view controller has / should have access to all of its subviews (recursively).

Comment: Because this is not possible. I can only create the IBAction in my "ViewClass" from which my View (.xib) inherits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your view hierarchy correctly, but I wouldn't recommend to put any logic that belongs to the model into the view.

I would make the ViewClass a subclass of UIControl so it can send events itself. And if the button was pressed you send a valueChangedEvent which is received by the viewController.

e.g:

```
// .h
@interface ViewClass : UIControl
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIButton *button;   // read only in public interface
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
@end

// .m
@interface ViewClass ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button;     // readwrite in private interface
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation ViewClass
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    // send valueChanged event to target
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

@end
```

and your viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewClass *myView = ...
    [myView addTarget:self action:@selector(myViewDidChangeValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (IBAction)myViewDidChangeValue:(ViewClass *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Send \"%@\" to server", sender.textField.text);
}
```

---

And you can use `addTarget:forControlEvents:` for subviews of a view as well. So you can actually connect the button of ViewClass to your viewController, you just might not be able to do it in Interface Builder.

```
[myView.button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Well, this seems like the approach I was looking for.

Comment: Also maybe it would be possible to register the ViewController as an Observer and to notify the ViewController in the IBAction and call the Method which contains the logic this way. What do you think about this idea?


But I'm wondering myself if this is the way apple thought about solving this problem...

Comment: There are various ways to solve this. If I want to connect views to viewControllers I usually use this target-action pattern because it takes the least afford. You could use delegates, which I usually use to connect viewControllers to viewControllers, but they require @protocols and usually don't make sense for a view that wants to send a single message. There are NSNotifications, which I use to connect unrelated models together. And last but not least Key-Value-Observation, which I rarely use. But that's just me. You could try them all. Which way to choose when is a huge topic by itself.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time and the competent answer. I will take a bit a deeper look at this topic and will use your target-action pattern for the moment. Seems like the best solution right now.
Thanks!